# How to Kill Process searching for Description with Loop via Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I'm trying to figure out how to create a batch file by searching a text on Description of the Process then killing it. I managed to find one on this stackoverflow. But how do I loop this search before killing it?

This is the batch file I made

```
:loop
powershell -command "(get-process | ? {$_.Description -like 'Internet*'} if $_.Description -ne "Internet*" ( GOTO LOOP) ELSE (get-process | ? {$_.Description -like 'Internet*'}).kill())"
```

Well I'm just trying to experiment it but it's not working. I have a super little knowledge about Powershell.

FYI: I'm doing this because I own a Computer shop and there are some people who are trying to use the Internet Download Manager Portable to download big files, I tried limiting the bandwidth of the idman.exe using NetLimiter, but they are just renaming the file to let say 1.exe or 2.exe etc., so that's why I will try using the task scheduler and run this batch file in the background.

Comment: why are you trying to mix constructs from 2 different languages in powershell interpreter?

Comment: So let me get this straight, you want to prevent all end users from using any executable which has a description, _(beginning internet)_, by creating a scheduled task which runs a batch file which runs a powershell command. Not only will this prevent the use of some executables which are not hogging your bandwidth it will also not prevent the use of any of the multitude of alternative download managers which will quick take it's place.

Comment: Wow, this is bad idea. If you want to block applications from running, use ex. AppLocker to prevent them from starting in the first place (if it's signed then you can block the publisher). If you only allow certain apps to access the internet, then you could use windows firewall to whitelist only those so unknown apps can't access internet (whitelisting requires planning)

Comment: I really don't have any other idea beside killing the process with using a powershell. I already knew the alternative download manager. By using Applocked and preventing internet download manager, they can just rename the file and then they can open it again. My Firewall is disabled because of a certain reason.

Comment: You can use Applocker with path, filehash and publisher (if exe is signed).. But do what you want. It sounds like you should start with getting control over your environment. If you can't block it, then use policies. If a user or customer doesn't follow the company's IT policy, then lock them out. There are always ways to bypass restrictions. When you finally have control over this software, they could just find a new similar program.

Comment: tried the Applocker and it seems in my "Timer" Computer is working properly while on the clients it's not, even though I created a rule that denying all exe. Well I'll just use the script below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure killing the process would be a good solution in your case, but if you trying to kill a process with a specific description, you can simply pipe the process to `Stop-Process`.

```
Get-Process | where {$_.Description -like "Internet*"} | Stop-Process
```

Comment: but it's still not looping nor checking if the process is there.

Comment: Wrap it in a loop.. ex `while($true) { Get-Process | where {$_.Description -like "Internet*"} | Stop-Process; Start-Sleep -Seconds 10 }`